# Zend Autoloader: custom library in Module-Folder

Tags: php, zend-framework

Why ist the Zend_Autoloader not able to load my Classes.
Tha path to the library should be: `/root/application/modules/modulexy/MyLib`
(Zend Version 1.12)

What i did:

1. In the public/index.php

> `set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
>       ...
>       realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/modulexy/MyLib'),
>       ...
>       )));`

1. In the Controller

   > $al = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
   >   $al->registerNamespace("MyLib_");

I don't want to move the library to  `/root/library`

Comment: What is the name of your class and how is the file named and placed into the lib?

Comment: The name of the Classes is somthing like that: MyLib_Model_Abstract and the Path is: MyLib/Model/Abstract.php

Comment: if u are using linux might be something to do with capital letters, try using lowercase letters..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your include path shouldn't include the "MyLib" part.

This should work:

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
      ...
      realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/modulexy'),
      ...
      )));
```

Alternatively, if you want that lib extra directory, you could have

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
      ...
      realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/modulexy/lib'),
      ...
      )));
```

And place your class "MyLib_Model_Abstract" in "/modules/modulexy/lib/MyLib/Model/Abstract.php